# Mock static method called from private static variable declared in class

Tags: junit, mockito, powermockito

Mock static method called from private static variable declared in class.

```
public class User{
   private static int refresh = readConfig();

   public static int readConfig(){
     // db call
   }
}
```

I tried to use powermockito to mock readConfig method but it is not working. I need to mock readConfig() at the time of classload.

```
PowerMockito.mockStatic(User.class);
PowerMockito.when(User.readConfig()).thenReturn(1);
```

Please let me know how to mock readConfig method.

Comment: `it is not working` is a rather broad statement. It does not tell us what is actually happening as apposed what was expected. Without a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that clarifies your specific problem or additional details to highlight exactly what was done, it’s hard to reproduce the problem, allowing a better understanding of what is being asked.

Comment: At the time PowerMockito.mockStatic(User.class) is executing, it is executing readConfig method also & giving error for database statement related mock.  At the time we are mocking the class readConfig is getting called. But in the next statement we are mocking it. That is why i clearly mentioned i have to mock readConfig() at the time of classload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you are not able to mock anything related to the `static` block,
you can tell `PowerMockito` to suppress it by annotating your test with [`SuppressStaticInitializationFor`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.powermock/powermock-core/2.0.2/org/powermock/core/classloader/annotations/SuppressStaticInitializationFor.html).

Note that doing so will not execute the `readConfig()` method and your `refresh` variable retains its default value (0 in this case).

But that does not seem to matter for you, as - judging by your comment - you mainly try to suppress the related database error. As the variable is private and you (have to) mock all the related methods its unlikely to be used during your test.

In doubt you would have to use `Reflections` if you need to set it to some specific value.

```java
package test;

import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.SuppressStaticInitializationFor;
import org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner;

class User {
   protected static int refresh = readConfig();

   public static int readConfig(){
       return -1;
   }
}

@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(StaticTest.class)
@SuppressStaticInitializationFor({"test.User"})
public class StaticTest {

    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception {

        PowerMockito.mockStatic(User.class);
        PowerMockito.when(User.readConfig()).thenReturn(42);

        Assert.assertEquals(0, User.refresh);
        Assert.assertEquals(42, User.readConfig());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with mocking static method called from final static variable.
Assume we have this class:

```
class Example {

public static final String name = "Example " + Post.getString();

   .
   .
   .
}
```

So I need mock static method getString() of class Post. And that should be done at the time of classload.

So the easiest way that I found out:

```
@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass()
{
    PowerMockito.mockStatic(Post.class);
    PowerMockito.when(Post.getString(anyString(), anyString())).thenReturn("");
}
```

And my annotations on top of the test class:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(Post.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"jdk.internal.reflect.*", "javax.management.*"})
```